# rails different currency formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, currency

I need to show user amount presented in different currencies. e.q. :

```
Your balance: $ 100 000.00
              € 70 000.00
              3 000 000,00 руб.
```

So I need to use `number_to_currency` three times with different locales(en, eu, ru). What is the right way to do it?

Comment: I've always wondered about how tying currency symbols to number formatting works. They're two *entirely different things*. The number format depends on the language of the content, while the currency symbol depends on what currency you happen to be talking about. For example, if I'm writing about US dollars on a Finnish website, I don't use the US method for writing the numeric part. Maybe I should blog about this or something...

Comment: and by the way, the € sign should come after the amount.

Comment: @Matti I agree with you; the two are definitely independent.

Comment: @allesklar It depends on the country: in Ireland it is before (they also use the €1,000.00 separator / delimiter format), however I think everywhere else in the Eurozone it is after :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you actually need different locales, because you have just balances in different currencies. You can simply pass additional arguments to number_to_currency. Something like this:

```
number_to_currency(70000.00, :unit => "&euro;", :separator => ".", :delimiter => " ", :format => "%u %n")
```

This will display: € 70 000.00

Additionally it seems that you can set :locale option when calling number_to_currency. It's not documented, but here is the part of the number_to_currency code:

```
defaults  = I18n.translate('number.format''number.format', :locale => options[:locale], :raise => true) rescue {}
currency  = I18n.translate('number.currency.format''number.currency.format', :locale => options[:locale], :raise => true) rescue {}
```

So you should be able to do something like:

```
 number_to_currency(70000.00, :locale => :ru)
```

Comment: I need to show 30 more currencies and I think there is some way to switch default locale in rails...

Comment: @SMiX I modified my answer to include :locale option.

Comment: It works! Thanks. There is not this option in official documentation.

Comment: This does not work.    number_to_currency(70000.00, :locale => :ru)

Comment: That syntax should work (see examples here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_currency). Most likely you don't have ru.yml file (do other Russian localizations work, like localized dates?). I don't think it's included by default, but you can get it from: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/ru.yml